# Usage of double/ float for integer type values

Tags: c

I am a newbie to programming.

I have a very basic question that 
"Can double or float type variable use for integer type values?"
I mean,e.g

```
float a = 2;
double b = 3.2;
```

Thank you

Comment: If you are new to programming - you should avoid as much as poissible usage of `float`s and `double`s until you can understand the basics about [floating point arithmetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Floating-point_arithmetic_operations), which is not trivial at all.

Comment: Integers can be just as confusing, like how in C and Java, 1/2*10 = 0 instead of 5. Floating point is just something you have to learn in programming, same as anything else.

Comment: I disagree. Understanding integer semantics takes maybe an hour at most - including all the corner cases like overflow. Understanding floating point enough not to make bad mistakes takes (depending on your mathematical background) somewhere between days and weeks, and if you want to *really* understand it enough to write good floating point code (not just to avoid floating point ;-) I would say it takes months or years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but there is a loss of precision if you use a float to store an integer.

Typically an integer uses 32 bits to store the number, meaning that it can hold a number in the range pus or minus 2 billion (approximately).

But a float uses 32 bits to store both the part before and after the decimal point, so there is not enough space to store as much precision. A float can store numbers greater than 2 billion, but the bigger the number, the more precision you lose, so if you store a number like 2134567891 in a float it might get changed to something like 2134567000, making it a bad idea to use floats to store precise numbers like an amount of money.

The good news is, a double uses 64 bits to store the number, so there's more than enough space to store an integer value with the same precision as an int, so as long as you use doubles, you shouldn't run into too many problems.

Comment: @ Nick. Thanks for your answer. i have another question that if  I have to add, multiply, subtract or divide the float values with integer type values, should I store the values in integer or in float. if no why. please explain. I know its a very basic question.

Comment: Not true, `(float)3 == 3` and that is guaranteed. Generally, IEEE floating point types store all integers in the range `-2^M .. 2^M`, where `M` is the number of mantissa bits, exactly.

Comment: Okay, maybe that was a bad example - I've taken out the part about small-value precision as it's not relevant (it's true for small fractional values, but the question was about integers). The part about large integers is still valid though.

Comment: That principle is false, or better, applies to fractions only. The main distinction is that (assuming `100 < 2^M`), `for(float i = 0; i != 100; i++)` is OK, will behave exactly as with `int`s and will NOT produce an infinite loop. OTOH, `for(float i = 0; i != 100; i+=0.1)` probably will. Also, when you haven't enough precision to store a given integer in a `float`, you can never get it rounded to a decimal number, only to some nearby integer (so you can't get 2134567000.09 in your other example).

Comment: Yeah, fair point. Serves me right for not bothering to look up the actual values produced. I think I still answered the question though!

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely impossible that float and double variables don't have much of a fraction, but better not, they lack precision.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, doubles and floats can have Integer values such as 0, 1, 2, 3, ...